# VBA : find strings in the textbox and change them into a certain string

Tags: vba, excel, debugging, excel-2007

I want to make a macro that changes every month in the textbox into a certain month entered in dialog box.
Here's what I wrote. There's no error, but it didn't do the work either. Could you help find the problem? Thank you.

```
Sub ChangeMonth()
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim shp As Shape
Dim xFindStr As String
Dim xReplace As String
Dim z As Integer
Set xWs = Application.Sheets("Mail")
xReplace = Application.InputBox("Replace to :", "Replacement", "", Type:=2)
'On Error Resume Next
For Each shp In xWs.Shapes
    xValue = shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text
    For x = 1 To 12
        shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text = VBA.Replace(xValue, MonthName(x), "xxxx")
    Next x
    shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text = VBA.Replace(xValue, "xxxx", xReplace)
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This main issue was that you were replacing all the MonthName by "xxxx", but you put that value in the shape's text directly, and yet you used `xValue` :

```
Sub ChangeMonth()
    Dim xwS As Worksheet
    Dim ShP As Shape
    Dim xFindStr As String
    Dim xReplace As String
    Dim z As Integer

    Set xwS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mail")
    xReplace = InputBox("Replace to :", "Replacement", "", Type:=2)

    'On Error Resume Next
    For Each ShP In xwS.Shapes
        xValue = ShP.TextFrame.Characters.Text
        For x = 1 To 12
            xValue = VBA.Replace(xValue, MonthName(x), xReplace)
        Next x
        ShP.TextFrame.Characters.Text = xValue
    Next ShP
End Sub
```

Comment: I see your logic. You are right. However, I had to add Applicaition. to this line :  xReplace = Application.InputBox("Replace to :", "Société Générale", "", Type:=2)   Otherwise  there's an error. I ran it. Now it replaces the months by "false". Do you know why?

Comment: @FrancisZHENG : `False`... did you hit "Cancel" maybe? Try adding `Msgbox xReplace` after the InputBox part. I probably didn't take your input right. Otherwise it seems to be ok.

Comment: I tested and there's no problem. I must have hit "Cancel", because it's working now. One last question, do you know how to write the code : if hit "Cancel" then don't make any replacement?

Comment: @FrancisZHENG : Just wrap the For Each inside an `IF xReplace<>vbCancel` or maybe `IF xReplace<>False`, if none of those are working, place a breakpoint and check the value of `xReplace` after you hit cancel! ;)

Comment: `If xReplace = False Then Exit Sub` will do the job

Comment: what you two suggested works both. Thank you very much !